# Discover WCF Rest Service from iOS5

Tags: ios, wcf, wcf-rest, service-discovery

I am building an iOS app that should communicate with a WCF Rest Service. They both will be on the same local network. While testing a have hardcoded the IP of the service, but that wont work when it will be deployed.

How can i get the service address, or connect to it in any way?

I was reading about WCF discovery but I don't know how I would implement this in iOS.

If it is of any help, im using WCF REST Service Template 40(CS)

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** How about using bonjour? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

WCF Discovery is an implementation of the [WS-Discovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Discovery) specification, which is an open standard.  As such there are a few implementations of it, for example one in Java called [java-ws-discovery](http://code.google.com/p/java-ws-discovery/), one in Python called [python-ws-discovery](http://code.google.com/p/python-ws-discovery/) and one in c sharp called [WS Discovery proxy](http://wsdiscoveryproxy.codeplex.com/).

I haven't found an implementation in Objective-C but given those three are all open source you may be able to port one, or at least the part you need (depending on whether you are able to understand one of those languages).

Comment: I'm not THAT good at Objective C :). Plus it seems like an over kill for my project. I'll try something with bonjour. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Fair enough - sadly a lot of IT departments (at least that I have come into contact with) don't allow bonjour but if that is not the case for you, it may be easier so go with that (though, given how little code there is in that Python version I am so tempted to have a go at porting it...).

Comment: if you ever do port it and open source it I'd love to take a look at it. Cheers

Comment: Is there any progress on Objective-C's WS-Discovery implementation?

Comment: I can't find Obj-C lib for WS-Discovery in 2015. Do you know any?